# Getting an error while invoking a REST service using Javascript

Tags: rest, xmlhttprequest

I have developed a REST Web service to get resources, I am able to access it through Java/Spring Template and even the xml response is coming if I type the URI on browser.

But when I invoke the same URI using XMLHttpRequest in Java script I am getting the below error.
**"XMLHttpRequest cannot load URI(actual uri with server name ..etc) . Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."**

**Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101.**

My JS code is as below.

```
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://localhost:8080/rest/apps", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
```

Please let me know what would be the problem and help me to resolve this.

Regards,
Sreedhar

Answer (score 0):

here [Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is the local file system, that you're loading the HTML page, that load call via a file:/// . the request is from the same origin. If you're trying to load from somewhere else then you will not get the Error.

[Check For this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)