# Javascript : Different behavior when run on machine and local server

Tags: javascript

Because my title is too short, I will explain more clearer. I have create a code in JavaScript . And I have two options to run :

1) Run on machine : simple click into html file.

2) Run on local server : mean I start Apache, and start this html file in localhost.

( `http://localhost:85/Javascript/index.html` for example)

When I choose solution 1, no thing happen. And when I choose solution 2, happen as I wish. But I don't know why.

Here is my code. Purpose : take a json file and process it.

```
<script>
        window.onload = function(){
            var url = "http://localhost:85/javascript/json1.json";  // problem here
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", url);
            request.onload = function(){
                if (request.status == 200){
                    update(request.responseText);
                }
            }
            request.send(null);
        };
function update(responseText){ // some code here }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use AJAX to read content from a different domain.

Javascript running from `file://whatever` cannot read `localhost:85`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you replace this line with the server's original path?

```
var url = "http://localhost:85/javascript/json1.json";
```

With

```
var url = "http://10.0.0.X:85/javascript/json1.json"; // Did you change the right path?
```

And make sure, the page is not called with the `file://` protocol!