# Angularjs cross origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Got the following problem with angularjs 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:... . Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP
My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angularr.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my app.js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function  ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when("/", {templateUrl:"first.html"})
        });
```

What should I do?

Comment: If you're not serving it from a webserver you should try doing that. Run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` or something like that.

Comment: No ,the files are locally

Comment: Probably the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669586/angularjs-http-load-data-from-local-disk-issue-in-ie9

Comment: Yep that is is running perfectly on firefox

Comment: testuser had it right. If you're developing locally using just a browser to view the files, Chrome will complain. You'll either need to run a server locally or use FF. Alternately, you can use something like JSFiddle or Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Chrome/Chromium instance with [the appropriate flag](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-web-security), e.g.:

```sh
chromium --disable-web-security
```

To allow access from local files to local files, there is [another remedy](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files):

```sh
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

See [*Run Chromium With Flags*](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) on the Chromium How-Tos, and here is [a complete reference for the command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

**Disclaimer:** While it's comfortable during development, this is not a substitute for running your app on an actual server, the easiest way would be launching a python HTTP server, as @testuser kindly suggested (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, or with python 3: `python3 -m http.server`).