# jQuery ".load" and jGrowl

Tags: jquery, jgrowl

I'm loading a HTML page using jQuery's .load method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#body_dynamic_css').load('/url/to/page');
});
```

I recently updated the version of jQuery to 1.7.2 from 1.4.2.  I used to be able to use jGrowl after loading the additional page but now I can't.  If I look at the console of the loaded page I have jGrowl and if I remove the load statement from the original page I have jGrowl but as soon as load is called I no longer have jGrowl.  Even doing the following works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#body_dynamic_css').load('/url/to/page', function() {
        $.jGrowl('Hello StackOverflow');
    });
});
```

The exact error message I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'jGrowl'
```

This happens when the original page calls

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Do stuff here
    $.jGrowl('message');
    // Do stuff here
});
```

From an externally loaded javascript file.

```
<script src="/assets/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, take a look here for a working example:
https://gist.github.com/stanlemon/5649378

Note that is very important whenever you are using $.load() that you are accessing your file over http(s) and not file://  When doing the latter you will run into 'Origin null' issues, see [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) for more information on that front.