# Retrieve the content of the JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JavaScript, I want to retrieve the content of the script files. These script files remain in local(in web page).

For example.
In web page, there is a script,

`<script src="tool.js"></script>`

Latter, I want to get the content of `tool.js` and process the retrieved result (like dump its content).

I have tried to use `jQuery.getScript`. However, it tells me that Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Do you run any web server on local?

Comment: No, I just need to read script file from website developed by other developers. In other words, I can't control these scripts directly, but I need to process them (like dump their contents in console).

Answer (score 0):

try an ajax like the following

```
$.ajax('/tool.js', {
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("call failed");
      }
});
```

Comment: Chrome still tells me that there is Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using `jquery.load()` and put its contents on an element and use `.html()`

```
<html>
</head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //setup ajax to work locally
        $.ajaxSetup({
           crossDomain: false,
            isLocal :true
        });
        $("#a").load('jquery.js', function() {
          alert($("#a").html());
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="a" style="display:none;"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**Browser Check:**
the code above works and tested in FF, Safari, Opera and IE

but if you keep on having problem with `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` then having a web server installed is needed as said here; [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

**Reference:**

http://api.jquery.com/load/

code for your disposal : http://jsfiddle.net/PeaH3/1/

Comment: Same problem as @Lars's suggestion and `.getScript` method

Comment: @YulongTian Please answer on my qquestion above your.

Comment: @Mahan Still same problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Still some problem. Finally I decide to put these logic into plugin(The project will have a plugin running under the browser).

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This lets you use any resource to obtain assets from an external domain. Do this first and either Mahan's or Lars's solution will work.

More info:
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: I add that `<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" content="*">` in `head`. However, it can't still work well in Chrome. All suggestions will produce `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` problem.

Comment: @YulongTian you need to add it to `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`