# Jquery ajax request always failing - Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code in on my desktop:

```
$(function () {
    $('#country_link').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/ajax.html',
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $("#country_slide").show('fast');
                $("#country_slide").html('<p>Loading</p>')
            }, 
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#country_slide").html(data);
                alert('request successful');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
                $("#country_slide").hide('fast');
            },
            complete : function() {
               $('.loader').hide();
            }, 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I also have an ajax.html file with the following content:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

When I click the link I always get the message "request failed". The message console gives me is this:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. test.html:1
```

I'm a bit confused, since these files are both local why does it complain about the origin?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: You are doing a CORS request. Your server must accept those, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: You can't run ajax on a file that is accessed using `file://`.  You'll need to set up a web server and run it on `127.0.0.1`

Comment: You need an apache server emulator as WAMP

Comment: Ok, I see. I edited my code to show the ajax.html. If someone adds this as an answer I can accept.

Comment: @roasted He doesn't *need* an apache server.  He needs a web server.  Any will do :)

Comment: @Archer  of course, you are right ;)