# Including a json file in a static html page (not hosted on a server)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I'm midway through setting up automation of my jasmine tests using grunt. I have Jasmine (and Istanbul) running fine in node and also a standalone html page that runs the tests. However, I only want to maintain one list of src files to include, so I have a json file which lists these in an array. I can include it using `require()` in my Gruntfile, but my plan to include it using ajax in the html page I now realise won't work as I will need to have a server running in order for ajax to work.

So my html page is at `file://foo/bar/page.html` and the json is in `file://foo/bar/my_data.json`.

Is there any other approach I can use to include a JSON file in a static html page which isn't on a server?

Comment: Do you mean that your html page is accessed like `file://foo/bar/page.html` and the json is in `file://foo/bar/my_data.json`?

Comment: yep - that's exactly right

Comment: You can use `FileReader` and parse contents with `JSON` object.

Comment: @ZlatanO Will FileReader accept relative paths? It needs to be agnostic between different developers' local environments

Comment: Yes. `FileReader` reads both local paths and remote URL's. I have used FileReader with Mozilla Firefox, but I belive that WebKit and IE had implemented the functionality. More on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader or take a tutorial on: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: There's no need to use FileReader.  I tested your setup with jQuery - and jQuery's `$.get("my_data.json", function(data) {...}, "json");` happily reads a local file.

Comment: @AleksG Have you tested `$.get` with local files, not stored on a running Web server?

Comment: @ZlatanO. Yes, that's exactly what I tested.  Both the HTML and the json files were on a local machine.  I loaded HTML into the browser as `file:///tmp/page.html` - and it happily read `/tmp/my_data.json` on the same machine.

Comment: @AleksG Than jQuery's Ajax implementation rules! I didn't know this... Thanks!

Comment: @AleksG Doesn't work in most browsers though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @ZlatanO - how are you creating your reference to the file? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code suggests it's only possible when developing a browser extension

Comment: No... I have used the same object when I created the Ajax Uploader... Reference yourself on the `FileReader`, not just on the `File` object. There you have `readAsDataUrl`, `readAsText` and other methods...

Comment: @wheresrhys I tested this on Firefox and Chrome - and it worked in both using `$.get` call.  I haven't tried `load` - but I suspect it may have different implementation.

Comment: This is not specific for jQuery AJAX implementation - just don't confuse `file://` with `http://localhost/` and use relative paths - everything must work as AJAX is restricted only by origin/domain (you may overcome this by sending proper header in HTTP)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This doesn't solve the general problem, but it turns out that grunt-contrib-jasmine creates its persistent specrunner file which can be used in the browser, so the list of source files can be maintained within the gruntfile (or in a separate json) and the specrunner html page will automatically get updated each time grunt is used to run the tests.