# Twitter :Application-only authentication error Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, cors

i am trying to send a application only authentication request to twitter to get the access_token .i write a javascript code

function getTwitterAuthorizeTokens() {
        return {oauth_token: "abcdefg", oauth_token_secret: "asdfasdfasfdasdf"};
    }

```
// Get the consumer key and secret
function getTwitterConsumerTokens() {
    return {key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"};
}
var s = encodeURIComponent(getTwitterConsumerTokens().key,'RFC 1738');
s += ':'+encodeURIComponent(getTwitterConsumerTokens().secret,'RFC 1738');
$( document ).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+s);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        },
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
        data: "grant_type=client_credentials",
        processData: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("successfull");
        }
});
```

when this script is loaded .it is giving me error in console

```
OPTIONS https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token 405 (Method Not Allowed) sinon-server-1.7.1.js:573
apply sinon-server-1.7.1.js:573
fakeXhr.(anonymous function) sinon-server-1.7.1.js:592
send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) index.html:143
e.resolveWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C jquery.min.js:2
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. index.html:1
```

how to resolve this error please guideline. i am following this link https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

when i host it using node.js .it is giving me error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?jsonp=success
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?jsonp=success. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. index.html:1
```

Comment: what is the point of having second parameter to [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function ?

Comment: Are you running it from a file system or a server?

Comment: in the link (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) that u should encode the parameters with RFC 1738 it is right now giving same result as provided but in future it will get changed.

Comment: @vsr from file system.

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta that must be the problem. Host it on a server(like apache or nginx) and try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: its giving the same error except Origin is not now null

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta You're using **client side code** for the API 1.1. This doesn't work! Put some bloody effort in and work with server side code, you don't use JavaScript to access the API any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending a cross domain ajax request from your browser, which is mostly not allowed for security reasons. You must send the request from your server instead of client's browser.