# Send json string to summary html page via ajax(get) as paramater

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How do you send a JSON string to another page using ajax get method? As a prac question we need to do this.

> Once the questions are answered, the user's name, age, questions and results (Hint: you may store both the
>   correct answer and the user's answer and do the comparison in the next task, but at minimum store a boolean
>   to indicate whether the user got the answer correct) need to be stored with JSON. The string needs to be sent
>   over GET to the summary page as a parameter. This time, use jQuery's AJAX. You may use $.get(...) for 5
>   marks, however, for the full 10 marks, use $.ajax(...).

I have tried everything but cannot get anyting to work.

```
function storeResults()
{
    /*var name = getUrlVars()["name"];
    var age = getUrlVars()["age"];
    var percent = correctAns / 6 * 100;
    details = {"name": name, "age": age, "percent": percent};
    var questions = {"q1": question1, "q2": question2, "q3": question3, "q4": question4, "q5": question5, "q6": question6};*/
    //localStorage.setItem("detail", JSON.stringify(details));
    var theObject = { p1: "v1", p2 : "v2" };

    var jqxhr =
    $.ajax({
      url: "summary.html",
      processData : false,
      type : "GET",
      data: JSON.stringify(theObject)
    })
     .done (function(data) { $('#ajaxDiv').html(data) })
     .fail (function()  { alert("Error ")   ; });
}

function getResults()
{
    /*var obj = JSON.parse($_GET["detail"]);
    $("#name").html(obj.name);*/
    /*$.get("results.json", function(data,status){
    alert("Status: " + status); alert("Data: " + data);
    });*/
    /*$.ajax({url: "results.json", 
    type: "get", 
    data:{det: JSON.stringify(details)}, 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json",
    //success: function(){window.location = "summary.html"}
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
    }});*/
}
```

This is my current code, everything is commented out because nothing wants to work. As far as I understand we are not allowed to use PHP

Comment: You can leave out the `var jqxhr=` but what does the console say and what does the summary page do with the passed data? The excercise sounds silly to me.

Comment: I know it is stupid, literally nothing happens

Comment: Console errors? Your commented getResults is certainly partly php. There is no point in passing a string to a html page that gets loaded using ajax

Comment: Oh yes I commented that out once I realised that $_GET is php, I kinda forgot and tried to use that and only realised later on that you cannot use $_GET in javascipt

Comment: No you use location.search but that is not available to the page when ajaxed

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer per se but [data between html pages](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/796727/Passing-Data-Between-HTML-Pages-Using-AJAX) might give you the insight you require

After careful thought and quick experiment, this post will point you in the correct direction [passing data from an html page to another in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216447/passing-data-from-an-html-page-to-another-in-javascript)

As one of the comments state that the Ajax is not for passing data between pages it's for client server async communication. I would suggest in future use the local session rather than posting or getting data for inter page use.

Comment: The most I have been able to do was make the url summary.html in the ajax method. This is my summary page. In my console error I can see that it actually adds parameters to that url, but then how do I access and navigate to that url?