# jQuery AJAX returns OPTIONS as opposed to GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to do an ajax call on a static teams.json file:

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

Here is my exact AJAX call:

```
this.testData = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "js/dummy-data/teams.json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that when I call `testData()`, What I see in the network tab of my Chrome inspector tools is something called "OPTIONS" as opposed to "GET".

I also see an error which states "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error...

All I want to do is return the json object and console.log it out. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Copy/paste the URL in your code into a new browser window's address bar. See what comes back. Your server may not be configured to spit out JSON files.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin.  It has a good explaination of Same Origin Policy issues.

Comment: I'm assuming this file is running off your local machine (`file:///`), right?  To use AJAX, your file needs to be on a webserver.

Comment: Yes. It was. I found that out as well. Thanks!