# Auto refreshing div with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Trying to refresh a div every 60 seconds, using the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load').fadeOut('slow').load('index.html #load').fadeIn("slow");
}, 60000);
</script>
```

Here is the corresponding div:

```
<div class = "well" id="load">
  <center><h3><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Mt.Gox</h3></center>
  <center><h3>&#579;1 = <?php echo $usd; ?> USD</h3></center>
<hr>
  <center><h3><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> BTC-e</h3></center>
  <center><h3>&#579;1 = <?php echo $usde; ?> USD</h3></center>
</div>
```

The div is currently not refreshing at all.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: You're probably missing the references to jQuery files. Try adding this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: <center></center> is deprecate. use css `text-align: center;` instead

Comment: What data is being loaded from the URL? Does it have an elemnt with ID `load`?

Comment: jsfiddle will be good to debug.. or share code with all included js.

Comment: are you expecting the div to hold new php vars on load().  you might want to use a different approach.  and $.ajax() call to a php generated json object.

Answer (score 3):

Ok that's because you are using the script incorrectly., You need to use callbacks as below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#load').fadeOut('slow',$(this).load('index.html #load', 
       function(){
          $(this).fadeIn("slow");
       })
    )
    }, 60000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I misunderstood the code a bit so ignore my original comment below!

---

Try to remove the **#load** in the url. It's perfectly valid according to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but I think in this case it can cause reduncancy.

That is, make it like this instead:

```
$('#load').fadeOut('slow').load('index.html').fadeIn("slow");
```

When you call .load() on an element it will load into that element, if you also specify the same element in the Url to load - I think it can cause a problem.

Comment: Nope, it's really just fine.

Comment: I could reproduce it at http://jsfiddle.net/BFtY6/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/BFtY6/1/ (using Chrome 30, maybe it differs between browsers)

Comment: Right, but in your example, there *is* no `#load` section in the loaded document. Of course it will fail when you say "load a section that does not exist". The `#load` in the function parameter isn't saying where to load the data - its a selector, telling jQuery which part of the *loaded* document should actually be used.

Comment: Ah, of course - I got a bit confused since they are both called #load :) Sorry for the confusion. Adding a second element with the same ID can not be a good idea however since they are supposed to be unique, maybe it could still be a reason for the error?

Comment: That's not what's going to happen. `load()` will pull the *contents* of the `#load` element from the loaded data, and replace the *contents* of the current document's `#load` element with that.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to be quiet now - I've got no luck in thinking today :)

Comment: Ok, changed the code to: <script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load').fadeOut('slow').load('index.html').fadeIn("slow");
}, 60000);
</script>
...and getting the following error: TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$('#load').fadeOut('slow').load('index.html').fadeIn("slow");

Comment: @MichaelHazelwood that's because, you forgot to include jquery library

Comment: jquery-1.9.1.min.js is included.

Comment: Is jQuery included before your script element?

Comment: yes jQuery is included before my script element, just after the opening head section.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this link: [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Also that issue, I think that you shouldn't load html data via file:/// URL. Why don't you load a div in the same file. Forexample:

> $('#load').fadeOut('slow').load($('#test').css('display', 'inline')).fadeIn("slow");

and the div tag is like this:

div id="test" style="display:none;"

Comment: Thanks, with style=display:none nothing is displayed at all -- not even the data available at page load. Secondly I still get the TypeError: $ is not a function error, despite the fact that jquery-1.9.1.min.js is included and all the other javascript items on my page are working fine.

Comment: If you want it is displayed at page load, so remove style=display:none and change the javascript code like this one: $('#load').fadeOut('slow').load('#test').fadeIn("slow"); Remember that div tag that has id "test" is in the same file. Hope this help.