# JQuery .load() is not working. but css applies

Tags: jquery, html

I have 1.html as same location as this pi.html

pi.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#content').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
        $('#content').load("1.html");
       return false;
    })
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body><a href="1.html">1.html</a>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

after a click the link, the css applys, but the .load() is not working.
any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: are you sure that the file path is correct and the style sheet is included in the HTML page?

Comment: there is no style sheet. the css applies because the jquery .css() runs.  I did this to test if the jquery works.    but the .load() is not work.  I can click the link see 1.html if i remove  return false;

Comment: You can catch the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) error to see if the page was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing this on a local machine and not on a web server, it will not work. It's an ajax function that must work on a http:// server. Otherwise, if your files are in the right places, EDIT: your code looks fine.

Check the console for more details CONTROL+SHIFT+J for the console in Google Chrome, when you click the load link.

Comment: the console shows:   OPTIONS file:///C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/myweb/1.html Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/myweb/1.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. pi.html:1

Comment: Which confirms this answer as correct. Stop trying to use Ajax without HTTP.

Comment: @user2788424 Correct. Ajax will not allow a null origin, I think it's something to do with server-side access props like 777,444 (all those access codes). Nevertheless, if its on a server, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it locally, Chrome\Safari will block .load() requests from the local filesystem.

You can use Firefox, or run Chrome using --allow-file-access-from-files as an option.

Also, running it on a webserver works fine.

EDIT: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13262673/2632329 will help.