# How to avoid "Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" running JavaScript from local drive?

Tags: javascript, cors, frontend

How to avoid "Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" error running JavaScript from local drive?
So I cannot modify server headers as there is no server. 
Thank you.

**That is not duplicate as solution offered at '[Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)' does not work, you can read about it there.**

Comment: The definitely best is to use a local webserver (xampp, easyphp, wamp etc), but you can also run Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag. It is explained more in-depth in the [linked dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8456538/1331430)'s answers.

Comment: Thank you but --allow-file-access-from-files does not seem to work for me

Comment: Well yes, you are always better off using a local server... There are a too many dupes of this ([hundreds at least](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow+origin+null+is+not+accepted+by&oq=site%3Astackoverflow+origin+null+is+not+accepted+by&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.11073j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+origin+null+is+not+accepted+allowed+by+Access-Control-Allow-Origin)), and every single one will tell you to use a local server or that flag.

Comment: As long as you don't provide info that differentiates your use case from the other hundreds of questions linked above, it is still a dupe, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

No. You will need a server like Mongoose (very simple download and run in your root). A very easy fix.

Comment: Can't I somehow play with Chrome settings to avoid having a server? I do not like the idea of having a server for some reason.

Comment: why Mongoose? There are plenty of options...

Comment: Sure, loads of server options. I was just suggesting a quick easy solution, its my 'go to' quick option.

Comment: Use a server. Don't try to do this with file URLs, it's pointless (and a simple http stack is easy as pie to run).