# jQuery - AJAX load() Method isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I'm trying to dynamically change the content of a div (#div1) with content from another HTML file (content.html) when a button is clicked (as is done [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)), but nothing happens when the button is clicked. Not to mention, the files are located side-by-side in a folder, so I'm really stumped.

Here's my code:

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("content.html");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**content.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!</h2>
<p id="p1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where does content reside in the file system relative to  index.html? Are there any errors that appear in the developer console?

Comment: You only want to load the specific HTML content you want displayed, not the `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: @gh9 Ooh, I see an error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/ajax2.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: what is <button> are you using html5 ? give buttonid and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a server**

Mostly ajax issues are due to the `Same Origin Policy`. There are many ways to fix this, I recommend you to use a local webserver. Setting up a local webserver is really easy:

you can use LAMP,
MAMP,
WAMP, or
XAMPP. Those are all free and easy to use. If you aren't scared to use the command line:

- Python 3.x by running `python -m http.server` from your local directory
- PHP 5.4.0+ by running
  [`php -S localhost:<port_number>`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

**Select only the body...**

Mostly, you don't want a second doctype in your code, so replace

```
$("#div1").load("content.html");
```

With

```
$("#div1").load("content.html body");
```

Comment: Which server entails the easiest installation?

Comment: I feel like [anvil for mac](http://anvilformac.com) is the easiest. (That's a mac specific one)

Comment: What about for Windows?