# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a node.js server which is running locally on my computer.  And I am developing html page with js-code:

```
var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

    var onCountComplete = function(response) {
        $scope.count = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function(reason) {
        $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
    };

    $http.get("http://localhost:1337/api/count")
        .then(onCountComplete, onError);

    $scope.message = "hello";
};
```

I get the error when I were running this code:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:1337/api/count`. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.

I have tried to launch the Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files key, but it doesn't helps.  Is there a way to avoid this error during development?

Comment: Is on your api server CORS enabled?

Comment: Can you try to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header on the server-side?

Comment: You doing cross-domain request and this is the problem. You have to either place server and client on the same domain or enable CORS on server

Comment: How can I do it (enable CORS on the server) in node.js case?

Comment: If you're using Express, [this link](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) may help.

Comment: You can serve the Angular code from `http://localhost:1337` and this should work okay

Comment: @demas What the scheme of web page the runs the script? If it's `file://`, that's your problem. If so, this is a duplicate of [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, you can try this solution. This has worked for me on a few small projects. Just add these lines to your .htaccess file. Customize as needed though, my example below is rather permissive and you may only need POST or a specific origin for example.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type"
```