# jQuery mobile won't work on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

So, I can run this on Firefox and it works just fine. But when running this on Chrome, I'm getting a loading icon which keeps just 'loading'.

Like this: http://prntscr.com/8erab4

On Firefox the result is just great, example: http://weveloped.com/app

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>HorizonApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Welcoming Page-->
    <div data-role="page" id="homepage">
    <div data-role="header" class="header">
      <a href="#panel" data-role="none"><i class="fa fa-bars left"></i></a>
      <h1>Horizon GPD</h1>
      <a href="#homepage" data-role="none"><i class="fa fa-home right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" id="panel">
        <div class="sideMenu">
          <ul>
            <li class="navTitle">Tijden</li>
            <li><a href="#tijdvak1">van 09:00 tot 11:00</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tijdvak2">van 11:30 tot 13:00</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tijdvak3">van 13:30 tot 15:00</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans serif;
}

/* Header */
.header {
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
}

.ui-page .ui-header {
    background-color: #013378;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.header a i {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FC7C00;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.header a i.left {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.header a i.right {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.header a:hover > i {
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Side Menu */

.sideMenu, .sideMenu ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.sideMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.sideMenu ul li.navTitle {
    height: 40px; line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #FC7C00;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight:700;
    text-align: center;
}

.sideMenu ul li {
    display: block;
}

.sideMenu ul li a {
    height: 40px; line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.sideMenu ul li a:hover {
color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(1, 51, 120, 0.8);
}

.ui-panel-inner {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.  It may be a dependency not loading for some reason.

Comment: I think this can be useful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385680/chrome-securityerror-loading-jquery-mobile-page-from-local-file-system

Answer (score 0):

Install WampServer on your computer, copy the folder of your project in c:\wamp\www\ , turn on the local server and run your jQuery Mobile page (localhost/folder-of-your-project/jquery-mobile-page).

You need a local server to run any jquery mobile page in Chrome

Regards