# Systrace Error. Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, systrace

I am trying to open the HTML file generated by systrace. When I click on one the block I used to get the selected slice information like "Duration", "Total Time" etc. But with the latest version of chrome that is not working.

**Tried on latest chrome(ver.45), chrome beta(ver.46) and chrome Dev(ver.47) version and I see the same problem across all the versions.**

I see that when I click on the slice, instead of showing the details, it throws error stating

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A
>   history state object with URL
>   'file:///C:/Users/ssundark/Desktop/vsync_off_default_sclk.html' cannot
>   be created in a document with origin 'null'.

Can someone please let me any work around to this problem ? or if there is some way we can open this file to know the selected slice information.

Comment: The file is generated once we run android systrace utility. It is expected to run out of the box. But with latest version of chrome it is not working. 
With older systrace dump I see that, "window.history.pushState({view_guid:this.guid_,selection_guid:b.guid});" but with latest systrace dump "window.history.pushState({view_guid:this.guid_,selection_guid:b.guid}, "");"

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it following the directions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13262673/1292598

Long story short: Start Chrome with the --allow-file-access-from-files flag.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Tried. Its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `window.history.pushState` throws an error when `window.history.state` is `null` or `undefined`.

To fix this problem, just do:

```
if (window.history.state) {
   window.history.pushState(state, title, href);
}
```

Comment: i have reactjs build and facing same issue, where to add this fix may i know ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution while building a client-side router was to make sure that I had a base href tag in my html document and then configure the router to have options to set the root of my router to use the base href while in html5 history mode. Both the base Href attribute and the root property in your code while using the HTML 5 History API should match otherwise I have found that you will get errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

this security error from browser, you must run on web server.
i'm test run in webstorm and it's worked!