# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replacestate'

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I can't figure out how to fix this error, everytime I test my app on Google Chrome this error occurs, but the app works well in Firefox. What should I do to fix this?

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/finalproject/index.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.

Comment: That's a security feature (same origin restriction) of chrome: [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) The question isn't about `replacestate` but the underlying problem is the same

Comment: what should i do to fix this?

Comment: it was working well on chrome a month ago, but now even my newly created apps produce the same error and only works on firefox

Comment: Read the linked question and the suggested answers :)

Comment: Its working now, thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a security feature (same origin restriction) of chrome.

This question isn't about `replacestate` but the underlying problem is the same:
[Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)