# Origin null is not allowed by Access Control-Allow-Origin , JSON file from computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am building a travel website where for the search destinations option I am getting the following error:

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

My json file is in my folder itself,
the following is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON('resort.json', function(data) {
                $("#searchresort").on("click", function() {
                    var userDept = $("input:checked").val();
                    var output = "<ul>";
                    for (var i in resort.resorts) {
                        if( (userDept == resort.resorts[i].destination) || (userDept == "Any") ) {
                            output+="<li>" + resort.resorts[i].picture + "<br> " + resort.resorts[i].name + "<br>" + resort.resorts[i].short_description + "<br> " +"<a href='" + resort.resorts[i].id + ".html'>Visit Page</a></li>";


                            // " -- " + data.users[i].dept+"<a href='" + data.users[i].id + ".html'>Visit Page</a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                    output+="</ul>";
                    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
                });
```

if anyone could help me out with this, it would be great.

Comment: You can't do that.  You need a server.

Comment: Possibly duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

No research done before posting this question

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers will not allow you to read files from a file:// origin.  So, if your web page is loaded by the browser directly from the file system with a file:// URL, then you can't read other files with file:// URLs even though it seems like it should be the "same origin".  This is apparently done for security reasons to avoid any possible ways for a web page to read files from your hard drive.

The browser reports `file://` as a `null` origin in that error message.

Though not recommended, some browsers have a command line argument or other preference settings that will allow local files to be accessed, but this comes with the usual security warnings.

The usual solution here is to run a local web server and load your files via the web server rather than directly from the file system.

Comment: @Harsh - Did this post answer your question?