# Cross-Origin Request Blocked elasticsearch

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

hi am running Elasticsearch version 2.3 and i have an Angular code to query like a search.when i run it i am getting this error even with http.cors.enabled set to true and also with http.cors.allow-origin to `/https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/`

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:9200/elastic/_search?size=50. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS
```

i don't understand what the problem is.

my request headers.

```
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8100
Host:   localhost:9200
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method:  POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

my console looks like this.
[image]

but if i put the request directly in the browser like this..i get correct output.

[image]

Comment: Are you loading your page via the file:/// protocol or is it served by a web server on localhost? A similar issue can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907355/elasticsearch-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-configuring-http-module/36907386#36907386)

Comment: via file://...does this make a difference???

Comment: If you read the link I shared you'll see it makes a difference since the Origin is null when loaded from the filesystem. You might get away by upgrading to 2.3.3 as I think they have fixed that CORS issue.

Comment: i tried running by installing a simple http server. but still its the same problem and i am running Elasticsearch 2.3.3

Comment: Can you update your question with the request headers you have in the HTTP request + response?

Comment: this is my request headers..

Comment: What happens if you hit `http://localhost:8100` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8100`?

Comment: its still the same problem...

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are tonnes of these questions flying around, it may be worth putting in a broad search on elastic search and cors

Comment: none of the answers seemed to help which i found in other forums.

Comment: finally solved it...i changed http.cors.allow-origin to "*" and somehow it worked

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding these lines to my yml, then restarting ES.

```
 http.cors.enabled : true
 http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
 http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
 http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length
 http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

Comment: test: curl --head http://localhost:9200 -H 'Origin: http://example.com'

Comment: It worked for me, but I have a query, Why no error occur when I access same data from c# code?

Comment: @TechieBoy because CORS is a security mechanism in browsers only; it doesn’t affect server code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the elastic cloud if someone needs it.

https://docs.elastic.co/search-ui/tutorials/elasticsearch

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept, x-elastic-client-meta
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the elasticsearch.yml, you can use this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) to disable the CORS.

Comment: This is good only for debugging, not viable solution to ask all of your users to install a Chrome extension to disable CORS.

Comment: @Mahdi: The chrome extension link is no more valid. Can you please update it if possible?

Answer (score -2):

For developing purposes, one can use the Chrome extension [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) as @Mahdi pointed out. The extension adds `(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)` rule to the response headers.