# CORS doesn't work with tomcat + javascript

Tags: javascript, http, tomcat, xmlhttprequest, cors

When sending a XMLHttpRequest

```
function requireCS(){
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url";
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Request", "categories");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {changes.
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
  }
}
http.send();
}
```

I get an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load -serverurl-. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
>   script.js:263 XHR failed loading: POST "-serverurl-".

I have the header set in web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
   <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
   <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
  <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-          Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
  <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-    Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
   <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Cannot figure out whats wrong.
Can you help me?

Comment: `Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`. Origin is usually `null` when you are accessing a html file from the file system - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin. If you are not accessing the file from file system, it would help if you could provide the request and response headers.

Answer (score 0):

To get CORS to work with POST you must

1. Set content type (which you are aready doing)
2. Send a dummy payload (!)

For example, this JavaScript works for me with  Chrome (v56 in OSX) and Tomcat v7.0.75:

```
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/MyServer/MyServlet/a/b";
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("POST", url, true);
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    var status = req.status;
                    var hundred = Math.floor(status / 100);
                    callback(hundred == 2);
                }
            };
            var dummyPayload = new Uint8Array(1);
            req.send(dummyPayload);
```

Here is my successful Tomcat CORS configuration in web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>180</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also got PUT to work with the above Tomcat config and the following JS:

```
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/MyServer/MyServlet/a/b";
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("PUT", url, true);
            req.responseType = "text";
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    var status = req.status;
                    var hundred = Math.floor(status / 100);
                    callback(hundred == 2);
                }
            };
            var text="Hello World";
            req.send(text);
```

I don't claim to understand why the above works.  But if my POST and PUT examples work for you then you can adapt them to do what you want bit by bit.