# POST Request then redirect to different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a post request to infusionsoft to store the data and then based on a user choice of something redirect them to the proper page.  For some reason the data is being sent but the form is not redirecting after?

The form looks something like this, but I removed alot of the fields...

```
<form id="infus_form" class="infusion-form" form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="1f37" />
    <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="Free" />
    <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

my javascript / ajax call is this, with the proper ending for the url..

```
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#infus_form").serialize(),
    url: "https://xi309.infusionsoft.com<APP>",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("HERE");
        var val = parseInt($('input[type=radio]:checked')[0].value);
        var urls;
        if (val != 1089){
            urls = "/free-thankyou";
        } else {
            urls = "/create-review";
        }
        window.location = urls;
    }
});
```

**Error:**

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Goto your browser console and paste the error here.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. I tried also using JSONP?

Comment: R u making ajax call from localhost?

Comment: @Ben I have added this error to your question, as I feel like it is very necessary for you to achieve a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)