# I can't fixed a problem of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have "three" files in one folder
1. **index**.html
2. **index**.js
3. **helper**.js

I want to export code from `helper.js` and import code to `index.js` (I already link up `index.js` to `index.html`).

I did like that
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="btn">click</button>


    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import btn from './helper'

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.alert('i am clicked')
})
```

and finally **helper.js**

```
export let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
```

Then I run **index.html** file in chrome browser.

Chrome browser showing this message in the console.

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

Please tell how can I solve that problem. I search on google and youtube, I did the same thing what they showed. As a result, the browser showing that massage.

Answer (score 7):

You need to include you import inside a module:

Try this:

```
<script type="module">
   import btn from './helper'
</script>
```

Reference: [ES Modules in Browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)

Comment: I tried **type="module"** but its showing error **Access to script at 'file:///D:/testing/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.**

Comment: Now it's another error. You trying to access a script without a origin. Browsers like chrome do not allow you to access files on the local filesystem with JavaScript. You need to install a web server like LiveServer.

Comment: i would not do it like that what did you tell.I want to solve it normally without do effects in index.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: your answer is confusing

Comment: what did they mean by **outside of module** ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to serve your files with a web server on some port, say 5500. Then point your browser to that port i.e. localhost:5500/

This will be the only way the browser will import other modules from another js file.

### See... [MDN Doc on Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts)

- You can use the npm package http-server.
- Or the extension Live Server if you are using Visual Studio Code.
- Or any other server that you like that will work on your system.

---

Next you will need to add type="module" to your script tag.

```
<button id="btn">click</button>


<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

And your index.js try this...

```
import { btn } from './helper.js'
```

Lastly your helper.js ....

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

export { btn };
```

---

You might also think about using the .mjs extention on js files that are module. To let enyone know that it is indeed a module.

Comment: finally i solved my problem..my problem was in .babelrc file...ok thank you

Comment: Good :) What was the problem in the .babelrc file? It might help others to edit your original question with your solution at the bottom. Happy coding!