# Getting error origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am calling AWS API gateway using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                var finalJson = {
                  "entityType": "abc",
                  "entityId": "123"
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    xApiKey : "api-key"
                    url : "api-gateway-url",
                    data : JSON.stringify(finalJson),
                    dataType : 'json',
                    timeout : 100000,
                    success : function(data){
                        alert('Congrats! You got the response');
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error : function(data){
                        alert('Error');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>API Gateway call</h2>
        <button type="button" id="btn">Request data</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

API Gateway has a POST method and it is linked with the Lambda function.
I have already enabled CORS in API gatewaye.
After clicking on the Request data button, showing the following error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API Gateway URL' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Please help, Thanks :)

Comment: I am also getting a similar problem in my project

Comment: This is working fine after configuring API Gateway from scratch by enabling CORS. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) not because of the API Gateway. If you configured the CORS configuration with `*` you should be able to call directly from frontend.